# Read multiple files using bash script/shell script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, netcdf

I am new in shell/bash scripting.
I want to extract data from multiple netcdf files using the bash or shell script.
Each file contains a time series of temperature values.
For example:

```
FileA.nc contains 20 20 21 22 23 24
FileB.nc contains 23 24 25 26 27 24
FileC.nc contains 21 20 19 18 22 23
```

I want to extract the values per file and merge the results of the three files.
The output should look like this saved as a csv file.

```
A 20 20 21 22 23 24
B 23 24 25 26 27 24
C 21 20 19 18 22 23
```

What is the easiest way to do this?
Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is `A,B and so on` single character stuff?

Comment: My awk script gives the expected output but it doesn't look like the valid csv file.

Comment: Expected output differs from the contents of the `fileC.nc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as-

```
for i in {A..C}
do 
echo -n "$i " >> master_file
cat File"$i".nc >> master_file
done
```

Now you'll have a huge file with appended individual files.
Now to make spaces into commas (if you want a .csv format)

```
sed -i 's/ /,/g' master_file
```

Comment: Your question suggested that the files only had the temperature data. You need to be clearer about what your individual input files contain. Please edit your question.

Comment: Many Thanks for the help, I deleted my previous comment here. I was processing the wrong file a while ago.This is already working for my problem.Many thanks again

Comment: If it's a valid solution then please 'accept' it as an answer.

Comment: The result should also contain a part of the file-name ie `A` in `FileA.nc` and so. This solution doesn't implement it.

Comment: @sjsam Yup, fair enough. Edited it to make it exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: @VarunMandalaparthy : Ah much better ++

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your friend :

```
$ arry=( file{A..C}.nc ) # store all the filenames in an array
$ # Then feed all the files to awk like below
$ awk '{printf "%s %s\n",gensub(/file(.)\.nc/,"\\1","1",FILENAME),$0}' "${arry[@]}" >newfile
$ cat newfile 
A 20 20 21 22 23 24
B 23 24 25 26 27 24
C 21 20 19 18 22 23
```

**Note**

This requires you have [[ gnu awk ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) which I suppose you already have.

Answer (score 1):

In AWK:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^file|\.nc$/,"",FILENAME); print FILENAME,$0}' file*.nc
A 20 20 21 22 23 24
B 23 24 25 26 27 24
C 21 20 19 18 22 23
```